# Bluetooth peripheral does not pair

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, cbperipheral

I have written an apple watch app to try to communicate with a bluetooth peripheral which has implemented some custom encryption and pairing process I already managed to implement correctly.

The device seems not to conform to standards and as such does not indicate that it needs encryption through its chatacteristic properties. After going through the pairing I can write values to it and recieve notifications.

The problem is that when I disconnect and connect again I have to go through the pairing process again. Also I have noticed that after pairing via other apps the device does a long beep sound which seems missing when I pair it through my app.

Is there any way to force pairing/binding in CoreBluetooth?

Comment: "through its chatacteristic propertied"  What does that mean?  Through its characteristic properties, maybe?

Comment: Yes, its „through its characteristic properties“. Fixed it, sorry